# What is the use of IEnumerable<IUserEventHandler> userEventHandlers in Orchard.User module

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I am wondering that what is the use of IEnumerable userEventHandlers in Account controller, defined in Orchard.User Module?

```
 [HttpPost]
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings",
            Justification = "Needs to take same parameter type as Controller.Redirect()")]
        public ActionResult LogOn(string userNameOrEmail, string password, string returnUrl) {
            var user = ValidateLogOn(userNameOrEmail, password);
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                var shape = _orchardServices.New.LogOn().Title(T("Log On").Text);
                return new ShapeResult(this, shape); 
            }

            _authenticationService.SignIn(user, false);
            foreach (var userEventHandler in _userEventHandlers) {
                userEventHandler.LoggedIn(user);
            }

            return this.RedirectLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would suggest that you can pass an IEnumerable containing IUserEventHandler. These will be called in sequence when the event occurs.

```
 foreach (var userEventHandler in _userEventHandlers) {
                userEventHandler.LoggedIn(user);
            }
```

I would imagine that you could have multiple subscribers that need to be concerned that a user has logged in, and this is a clean way of notifying them.

Comment: thanks @Chris, I want to know that kind of user event can be called here? sorry for my poor English..

Comment: I would say any that implements IUserEventHandler.

Comment: If you consider this an answer, would appreciate you mark it as such. Glad to help